# TFS 2013 to TFS 2013 synchronization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We are trying to work on a solution to synchronize two TFS 2013
servers.

We have two TFS 2013 servers, one in the development environment
 (let's say TFS 2013 Development) and the other in the production
 environment (TFS 2013 Production).

We need to be able to:

- Synchronize pieces of code from TFS 2013 Development to TFS 2013
  Production on an as needed basis.
- Synchronize the TFS tasks and work
  items between TFS 2013 Development and TFS 2013 Production. This
  should happen on an immediate basis and should be bi-directional. That
  is, when any changes are made to the work items/tasks in either TFS
  2013 Development or TFS 2013 Production it should immediately be
  reflected on the other TFS server respectively.

We have started
 looking into the above and tried using the TFS integration platform
 for synchronizing code between the TFS 2013 development and TFS 2013
 Production servers.

Hence we basically have three questions

1. Is TFS 2013 to TFS 2013 code/work item synchronization supported by the TFS integration platform tool?
2. How can we go about doing the Synchronization for the code
   repositories and work items as described above for TFS 2013 to TFS
   2013?
3. Is synchronization a new direct feature of TFS 2013, and can this
   be done without any third party tools?

Comment: Can you explain a bit of your scenario? The two instances are in the same company/organization? Why not merging them? Are they remote?

Comment: These two instances are in different company/organisation i.e two different networks. And also they are remote.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, I don't understand the setup of your systems. TFS generally lives in 1 instance and 1 only. TFS *is* a production environment for the development team. It doesn't make sense to have two TFS systems and have them synchronize to make this separation.

If you need to create secure snapshots of your sources, you can create branches and secure these. If you need to promote the results, run a build and use the published build artifacts to install to the production environment.

Having your teams work on two different TFS environments at the same time is a very strange requirement.

### To just answer your questions:

Now to answer your questions:

1. **TFS Integration Tools**
   It's a feature of the tool, and as long as you use the TFS Integration **Tools** (the version available from the Visual Studio gallery), [Microsoft provides paid support](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe). The TFS Integration **Platform** doesn't come with the same level of support. The TFS Integration Tools do not synchronize all data between environments, work item Tags, Test Results, Check-in notes, Labels, Permissions, Workspaces, Pending Changes, Shelvesets, File encodings, Subscriptions, Test Cases, Check-in policies, Reports, Team Portal / SharePoint, Process Templates, Work item queries, Builds, Warehouse data are not supported.
2. **setting up** You'd setup two syncs, one bi-directional sync for work one one-directional for sources and pray. There are so many things that can go wrong in this situation, as the sync is not transactional across environments and certain actions can happen synchronously on both environments that will put you in a stuck state. Generally when syncing between two systems you'd make one system master for a specific piece of data and you son't touch them on the other environment. This scenario is a nightmare waiting to haunt you until you turn it off.
    For the source sync, you might opt for a manual checkout/checkin process instead.
3. **Out of the box?** No, this is not a supported scenario in TFS out of the box. There is the [Integration tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) (which you've already found) and there are a few 3rd party commercial tools like [OpsHub](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim) and [TaskTop](https://www.tasktop.com/visual-studio-and-tfs-integrations).

Comment: From TFS integration Tools page: TFS Integration Tools were designed to work with Team Foundation Server 2012 and earlier. Use of these integration tools with TFS 2013 and 2015 may cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. TFS Integration Platform (March 2012 Release) supports only TFS2012
2. You can write your own synchronization tool using TFS API.
3. No. TFS2013 doesn't have this feature.

Comment: It supports TFS 2013 as well, but you need to install the TFS 2012 Client Object Model to connect.

Comment: You mean TFS2013 Client Object Model?

Comment: No. To connect the TFS Integration Tools to TFS 2013, you need to install the TFS 2012 Client Object Model. I know, confusing, but that is how it works.